# Return same weekday vertically in the calendar - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking to return all the dates vertically as shown in the calendar below.

[image]

For example, if I were to click on Tuesday I should be able to return

- 03/03/2020
- 02/06/2020
- 01/09/2020
- 03/11/2020
- 01/12/2020

Currently I have all the weekday in one whole year, but I haven't figured how to filter the dates that I don't want to based on the calendar shown.

```
date = Date.parse("09-01-2020").to_date
dates_selected = (date..date.end_of_year).group_by(&:wday)[date.wday]
# return all the dates on Wednesday

# filter the dates that are irrelevant
```

Any insight on how I can work this out? Thanks.

**Update 1**

I used this format because I want to schedule the working day or rest day in a vertical row. I managed to work it out using Javascript to extract the dates. I just wonder if I can return all the dates by using ruby only.

**Update 2**

To avoid confusion, I'm using year 2020 calendar. Thanks Amadan for pointing out.

[image]

Comment: I'm curious: where does that calendar layout come from? What's the advantage of aligning the months by day of the week?

Comment: @Stefan I've updated the screenshot. The second one is my current application's calendar layout. I'm working on a shift scheduling, so my understanding is that it would be more logical to for a manager to schedule shifts by every Wednesday vs every 1st of March.

Comment: Describe the logic behind your calendar.

Comment: @Yewness every Wednesday makes sense, but why would you want to select such column of Wednesdays? What do the selected dates (e.g. Mar 3, Jun 2, Sep 1, Nov 3, Dec 1) have in common?

Comment: @Stefan: They're all Tuesdays of the first week of the month (if that week has a Tuesday), where the first week of the month is the week containing the first day of the month (i.e. not using the "commercial week").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `date.day + (date.wday - date.day + 1) % 7` comes out as the column number in your calendar. Thus, just select those dates that have the same column:

```
require 'date'

private def column_of(date)
  date.day + (date.wday - date.day + 1) % 7
end
def dates_from_same_column_as(date, range)
  column_of_date = column_of(date)
  range.select { |d| column_of(d) == column_of_date }
end

year = Date.parse('2020-01-01')..Date.parse('2020-12-31')
date = Date.parse('2020-03-03')
dates_from_same_column_as(date, year).map(&:to_s)
# => ["2020-03-03", "2020-06-02", "2020-09-01", "2020-11-03", "2020-12-01"]
```

Comment: Thanks, the answer works according to what I need. How did you manage to come up this?
date.day + (date.wday - date.day + 1) % 7

Comment: Hmm... Not sure if I'll be able to explain properly, as it's mostly intuition. First, every row is offset by the weekday of the first of the month (so column is `date.day + something`). If 1st is Sunday (0), offset is 0; if 1st is Monday (1), offset is 1; etc. But we don't have the 1st of the month. Can we know the day of the week of the first of the month if we know the day of the week of an arbitrary day in the month? We know weeks repeat every 7 days, and the remainder is the distance to the 1st.

Comment: The structure was beautiful. Thanks for the explanation. :)

Comment: I almost convinced myself there was an error while comparing my results for 2020 with your 2019 table lol... Never mind, seems it's all okay.

Comment: I've updated the latest version for 2020. lol Hope I didn't confuse others that came looking for the answer as well.